# fetching route from vendor through routes/web.php

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.6

I have this route included in my `web.php` in my routes folder.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','namespace'=>'Admin', 'middleware' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {

Route::group(['prefix' => 'filemanager'], function () {
\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
 });

});
```

My issue is whenever I run `php artisan route:list` I get the following **error**:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\LfmController does not exist
```

The `Lfm` controller is inside my vendor folder and I've been scouting around the internet for a solution and applied many different ways for the route change and the only way I got it to work is by using the route provided by default from the package. But if I use that, I use lose my admin authentication I'm hoping someone could give me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong here?

I would really appreciate that! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change the namespace to vendor name, by default it looks in App. eg) 'namespace' => 'UniSharp'

Comment: It didn't work either, still having the same issue

Comment: make it separate route group, do not put inside the Admin namespace Route::group(['namespace' => 'UniSharp'], function () {
\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
 });

Comment: Yes I did that and i still had the same error. Instead I'm manually writing the routes under the admin group and got it working

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution. I am using Laravel 5.4

Instead of putting the code in `routes/web.php`, put it in **RouteServiceProvider**, so the default namespace is not set yet;

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
        \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
    });

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}
```

Comment: That is really a great approach. This works well with laravel 5.4 but I'm using laravel 5.6 and I've tried a similar approach it didn't work. I'm also using this on my admin panel that has a separate group and prefix. What works is to manually write the routes in web.php and set the  'use_package_routes' option to false in config/lfm.php. I'll post my routes as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For laravel 5.6 and above,

Go to config/lfm.php and set 'use_package_routes' to false.

In routes/web.php use the following routes (this is an example, might change adhering to your prefix etc.):

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','namespace'=>'Admin', 'middleware' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {

        Route::get('/filemanager', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\LfmController@show')->name('show');
        Route::any('/filemanager/upload', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\UploadController@upload')->name('unisharp.lfm.upload');
        Route::get('/filemanager/errors', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\LfmController@getErrors')->name('getErrors');
        Route::get('/filemanager/jsonitems', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\ItemsController@getItems')->name('getItems');
        Route::get('/filemanager/move', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\ItemsController@move')->name('move');
        Route::get('/filemanager/domove', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\ItemsController@move')->name('domove');
        Route::get('/filemanager/newfolder', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\FolderController@getAddfolder')->name('getAddfolder');
        Route::get('/filemanager/folders', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\FolderController@getFolders')->name('getFolders');
        Route::get('/filemanager/crop', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\CropController@getCrop')->name('getCrop');
        Route::get('/filemanager/cropimage', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\CropController@getCropimage')->name('getCropimage');
        Route::get('/filemanager/cropnewimage', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\CropController@getNewCropimage')->name('getCropimage');
        Route::get('/filemanager/rename', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\RenameController@getRename')->name('getRename');
        Route::get('/filemanager/resize', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\ResizeController@getResize')->name('getResize');
        Route::get('/filemanager/doresize', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\ResizeController@performResize')->name('performResize');
        Route::get('/filemanager/download', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\DownloadController@getDownload')->name('getDownload');
        Route::get('/filemanager/delete', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\DeleteController@getDelete')->name('getDelete');
        Route::get('/filemanager/demo', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\DemoController@index')->name('getDelete');


});
```